# Duplicate ActionBar Buttons on Rotation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I've tried to find an answer about this but with no luck. I have a **fragment** that has an a menu item called 'menu_roi_result_calc'. Every time there is a screen rotation, a new menu item is created. The code is shown below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_roi_result_calc, menu);
    return true;
}
```

However, after a couple of screen rotations, this is what I get:

[image: multiple actionbar menu items]

I get the feeling this is due to the fact that the menu items are being recreated at every rotation, therefore adding a new item every time a rotation occurs. How do I get this to stop? How can I check if the item is there and prevent from recreating it again? Any code example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Other than the code you show here, do you manually add/remove any buttons in the menu in any other part of your code?

Comment: Hi @AlexStyl, no, all I have is a containing Activity which calls onCreateOptionsMenu to add the 'Help' button (no problem there). This same activity hosts two fragments side by side. One of the fragments has a call to onCreateOptionsMenu to add the 'Share' action bar button (the one you see being repeated on screen). The issue seems to be with the **fragment** call to onCreateOptionsMenu. I should say that I'm developing exclusively for API level 21 and up. It occurred to me that perhaps this is happening due to handling the hosting activity improperly. But this is just a guess.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to have any issues. Is it possible that you are adding the fragments to the activity dynamically? If you do that, do you make sure if the activity is being recreated not to add the fragments again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out what the issue was. I was not reusing the original tagged fragments. All I had to do was make sure to check `savedInstanceState` and check if a tagged fragment had already been created... if so reuse the same fragment instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 6):

You must clear your menu object before adding items. I had the same problem and this was the best solution that I've found.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_roi_result_calc, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: What if I had multiple fragments each with its own menu?

Comment: You can create options menu in each fragment the same way. Override the "onCreateOptionsMenu " of each fragment.

Comment: I did not express myself correctly. Multiple fragments with their own menus *displayed* at the same time. Isn't the `Menu menu` instance provided by the activity and therefore common for the activity and all its fragments? If I understand correctly the last fragment to call `onCreateOptionsMenu` would overwrite the whole menu with just its own. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hımm. Now I understand you. I have no idea about this situation actually.

Answer (score 1):

as workaround you could clear the menu, before inflating it again, calling [clear](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#clear())

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_roi_result_calc, menu);
    return true;
}
```

it removes all entries from the menu, leaving it as it had just been created

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate your application your activity is destroyed and a new one is created. If you are attaching your fragment to the activity where it is being created than it will have the old one attached and will attach a new one. To avoid this I would do something like below. This will remove all of the current fragments and host whatever yours is.
    `FragmentManager fm = new FragmentManager();
    for(Fragment aFrag : fm.getFragments()) {
        fm.beginTransaction().remove(aFrag).commit();
    }
    fragment = createFragment(new Fragment());
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.YouGetThePicture, fragment).commit();`